# Problema con puntero y estructura

Tags: c

Teniendo el siguiente codigo:

```
DWORD WINAPI redirect(LPVOID param)
{
SOCKET rsock, csock;
SOCKADDR_IN rssin, cssin;
rs rs2;
DWORD id;

rs2 = *((rs *)param);
rsock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
WSAAsyncSelect(rsock, 0, WM_USER + 1, FD_READ);
memset(&rssin, 0, sizeof(rssin));
rssin.sin_family = AF_INET;
rssin.sin_port = htons(rs2.lport);
bind(rsock, (SOCKADDR *)&rssin, sizeof(rssin));

while(1) {
    if (listen(rsock, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR) break;
    csock = accept(rsock, (SOCKADDR *)&cssin, NULL);
    if (csock != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        rs2.csock = csock;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &redirectloop, (void *)&rs2, 0, &id);
    }
}

closesocket(csock);
closesocket(rsock);

return 0;
}
```

No entiendo muy bien que esta haciendo este puntero en esta estructura `rs2 = *((rs *)param);`

Comment: Lo siento, pero gracias por la info.

Comment: Lo siento no, si hay respuestas que solucionan tu problema, por favor, márcalas como solución. Así es como funciona [es.so] y, si tu no aportas tu granito de arena, es probable que nosotros dejemos de responderte. Por otro lado, si las respuestas no solucionan tu problema deberías usar el sistema de comentarios para indicar los problemas que estás encontrando así como los motivos que hacen que las respuestas no sean válidas.

Comment: Lo voy a hacer a partir de ahora, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, stackoverflow me viene bien para la universidad y me gustaría que siguiese siendo así.

Comment: Una pregunta un poco estúpida pero... yo he marcado las que me gustan con un tick hacia arriba, ¿ como  podría marcas las respuesta correcta?

Comment: Hay una marca debajo de la puntuación; en el [tour] se ve un ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por facilidad de explicación, este código equivalente:

```
DWORD WINAPI redirect(LPVOID param)
{
   rs rs2, *pRs;

   pRs = (rs *)param;
   rs2 = *pRs;
```

`param` es LPVOID, que es un puntero sin tipo definido (`void *`, si te suena de algo).

`rs2` es una variable del tipo `rs`, que supongo será un `struct`.

`(rs *) param` es un cast, indica al compilador que `param` es un `rs *`, un puntero que apunta a una estructura de tipo `rs`

`*pRs` hace una dereferenciación, quiere decir que se tome el valor de la estructura `rs` apuntada.

`rs2 = *pRs` copia los valores de la estructura dereferenciada en `rs2`.

Se ve más fácil con valores concretos, en este caso `int`.

```
int *pInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // `pInt` apunta a una dirección X
*pInt = 6;                              // Metemos 6 en la dirección X
LPVOID param = (LPVOID) pInt           // param es X
int valor, *pValor;
pValor = (int *)param;                  // cast, pValor es X
valor = *pValor;                        // dereferencia, valor es 6 (el contenido de la dirección X).
```